# how Import data into a database existing in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I have a program for the company 
This company is more than one section and the database  is the same status in each section 
Ardid and that the imported data from the branches every day or as needed to the database in the Head Office and sent via Aldata Balimiol for example, how can I, and no error message that the data already exists or tables 
Please help put an example of that, thanks
fatah_q@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question.  Are you trying to make several existing databases contain the same information?  Or are you trying to insert some information into multiple separate databases?